# Get MPI communicator handle in Rmpi

Tags: r, c, mpi

I'm working with the Rmpi library and I would like to pass the MPI communicator handle to a C program for further processing. How can we get the handle of the MPI communicator in R? Somewhere, in the internals of Rmpi, this handle must be stored...

Comment: The source code is readily available.

Answer (score 1):

The pbdMPI library is a derivation and rethinking of Rmpi aimed at running R on HPC clusters. It has the capability to accept a communicator and hand it off to other codes. Look at "8. Q: Can pbdMPI take or export communicators?" on p.20 of https://rdrr.io/cran/pbdMPI/f/inst/doc/pbdMPI-guide.pdf.

The translation of an Rmpi code to pbdMPI should be easy, assuming the Rmpi code was built to run in SPMD batch mode.

The GitHub version RBigData/pbdMPI is most up to date and ahead of the CRAN version.